# Display another time than the system time

Tags: windows, windows-10, time

I'm one of those people that is constantly late for everything. Therefore I set my PC clock 5 mins into the future. So if it's 08:45 AM, I already see 08:50 AM on my computer.

Some apps however require the system clock to be pretty precise to the real time, e.g my [Cloudflare WARP Client](https://developers.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-one/faq/teams-troubleshooting/#i-tried-to-register-the-warp-client-with-my-zero-trust-domain-but-received-the-following-error-messages-authentication-expired-and-registration-error-please-try-again-later).

Can i set my system clock to the [exact time](https://time.is/), but let it display the time +5 mins for me?

I mean in places like these:

[image: sysclock01]

[image: sysclock02]

Comment: Keep accurate system time (everything will work better).  Set alarms 5 to 10 minutes ahead of time on your smart phone.

Comment: @John That would require me to be a structured, well organized person. I'm working on it, but I have a long way to go :). I know that accurate system time is basically a must. That's why I asked this question. Maybe someone knows a way to trick around with the displayed time (not the actual time).

Comment: The [Fuzzy Clock](https://github.com/m66n/fuzzyclock) might work on Windows 10 (or might not) and could hide enough of the time that you have to actually pay attention to it yourself.

Comment: Why not just set an alarm to go off 5 minutes early?